Calculate the angle $x$ in the circle below
If $ \overparen{\mathit{MQN}}=240^\circ$, calculate $x^\circ$, with $M$ and $N$ being points of tangency.
(Answer: $30^\circ$)

I think:
Let $O$ be the center of circle:
$ \overparen{\mathit{MQN}}=240^\circ \implies \angle \mathit{MON} = 360^\circ -240^\circ =120^\circ $
$\angle \mathit{OMN} \cong \angle \mathit{ONM} = \frac{180^\circ -120^\circ}{2} = 30^\circ $
$\mathit{AMNO}$ is cyclic
$\angle \mathit{NAM} = 180^\circ-120^\circ = 60^\circ $
How do I continue from here?

Is $BC$ tangent to circle $QMN$?  How are points $B$ and $C$ determined? Clarify construction?

@EdwardPorcella  The question is exactly this. Only the drawing and data provided. There is no constructive process of the figure and it would not make sense because that way we would have the solution. Apparently $BC$ is tangent to the circumference

We have $\angle NCM={1\over2}\angle NBM$, because points $CNM$ lie on the same circle with center $B$ and $\angle NBM$ is then the central angle corresponding to inscribed angle $\angle NCM$.
PROOF.
Let $R=AB=AC$ be the radius of the quarter circle, $r=MO=NO$ the radius of the tangent circle. Then (see figure below):
$$
AG^2=AO^2-OG^2=(R+r)^2-r^2=R^2+2Rr\\
OB^2=AG^2+(R-r)^2=2R^2+r^2\\
BM^2=OB^2-r^2=2R^2=BC^2
$$
It only remains to note that $\overparen{\mathit{MQN}}=240°$
implies $\angle MON=120°$ and $\angle MBN=60°$.


$BM^2=2R^2=BC^2$.  Very nice. (+1)

Excellent my friend..thanks

Just one question: where did they come from $OB^2=AG^2+(R-r)^2$

@petaarantes Just consider trapezoid $AGOD$ and drop a perpendicular from $O$ to $AB$.

Understood..thanks
